# How to check if all values of column are same in oracle

Tags: oracle, group-by

I have a source table(Oracle DB) with below sample data from which I wanted to check if particular column(col3) values are same against column1. If so populate the new field as "Y" else "N".

```
Sample source table
SRC_TABLE
col1    col2        col3    col4    col5    ....colx
-----   ---------   ------  ----    -----   --------
ID001   SUPLIER_1   121.00  abc     123     ...
ID001   SUPLIER_2   100     abc     123     ...
ID001   SUPLIER_3   201.12  abc     123     ...

ID002   SUPLIER_1   150.00  abc     123     ...
ID002   SUPLIER_3   150     abc     123     ...
```

From the above table I want to check if col3 is same for the given col1 group and populate as "Y" if they are same else "N" as shown below in New_Field column.

```
col1    col2        col3    col4    col5    ....colx    New_Field
-----   ---------   ------  ----    -----   --------    ---------
ID001   SUPLIER_1   121.00  abc     123     ...         N
ID001   SUPLIER_2   100     abc     123     ...         N
ID001   SUPLIER_3   201.12  abc     123     ...         N
                                                        
ID002   SUPLIER_1   150.00  abc     123     ...         Y
ID002   SUPLIER_3   150     abc     123     ...         Y
```

I don't have authority to get the changes manipulated in source, I wanted to derive the calculations based on the source data and load into target. I have tried using group by while fetching data from source along with select statement but getting error as not a group by expression. Any help to achieve the desired output is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    .
    .
    .
    .
    colx,
    case when count(distinct col3) > 1 then 'N' else 'Y' end as new_field
from src_table
group by col1,col2,col4,col5...colx
```

Adding new_field in the group by clause returns invalid identifier error and If I remove that from group by getting not a group by expression error as shown above. Not sure how to get the desired result.

Comment: You need to add col3 in Group by instead of new_field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @kfinity said above, you can really get it using the analytic window function `count()over`, but using `count(distinct col3) over(partition by col1)` instead of `count(*) over(partition by col1,col3)`:

```sql
select
   s.*
  ,case count(distinct col3)over(partition by col1)
     when 1 then 'Y' 
     else 'N' 
   end as new_field
from SRC_TABLE s;
```

Full test case with sample data:

```
with SRC_TABLE(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) as
(
select 'ID001','SUPLIER_1',121.00, 'abc',123 from dual union all
select 'ID001','SUPLIER_2',100   , 'abc',123 from dual union all
select 'ID001','SUPLIER_3',201.12, 'abc',123 from dual union all
select 'ID002','SUPLIER_1',150.00, 'abc',123 from dual union all
select 'ID002','SUPLIER_3',150   , 'abc',123 from dual union all

select 'ID003','SUPLIER_1',100   , 'abc',123 from dual union all
select 'ID003','SUPLIER_2',100   , 'abc',123 from dual union all
select 'ID003','SUPLIER_3',201.12, 'abc',123 from dual 
)
select
   s.*
  ,case count(distinct col3)over(partition by col1)
     when 1 then 'Y' 
     else 'N' 
   end as new_field
from SRC_TABLE s;
```

Results:

```
COL1  COL2            COL3 COL       COL5 N
----- --------- ---------- --- ---------- -
ID001 SUPLIER_2        100 abc        123 N
ID001 SUPLIER_1        121 abc        123 N
ID001 SUPLIER_3     201.12 abc        123 N
ID002 SUPLIER_1        150 abc        123 Y
ID002 SUPLIER_3        150 abc        123 Y
ID003 SUPLIER_1        100 abc        123 N
ID003 SUPLIER_2        100 abc        123 N
ID003 SUPLIER_3     201.12 abc        123 N

8 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you want a window function.

```
select
    src_table.*,
    case when count(*) over (partition by col1, col3) = 1 then 'N' else 'Y' end as new_field
from src_table
```

The window partition in this case are the values that you want to be unique (col1 and col3), so a `count(*)` over that window will return the number of duplicate rows you have in the table (for that specific col1+col3 combination).

I notice that you have both `150` and `150.00` as values, so you might need to do `(partition by col1, to_number(col3))`

Comment: Thanks @kfinity... However seems like this wasn't giving the desired as the partition has been used against col1 & col3 which resulted say for example if col1 has same value and col3 has different values like below `col1 as ID003 and col3 as 100,100,120` it gives me Y for col3 120 entry and N for rest of the entries for col3 100.  Just used following snippet to get the desired result which suggested by @sayan `case when count(distinct col3) over (partition by col1) = 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end `